# Need to remove NaNs in a particular cell of dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like below,

| - | t | c | i |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 'a' | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | NaN | 'b' | NaN |
| 2 | NaN | NaN | 'c' |

But  I need a dataframe like below,

| - | t | c | i |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' |

Could someone please let me know how to do this in pandas?

Comment: What happens when you get an odd number of nans?

Comment: Can provide a larger example? Like this it's hard to tell what this should be based on. Do you always have the same number of nans in each column?

Comment: Have you tried splitting off each column as a series, dropping the nans and recombining?

Comment: I have tried but on combining those columns, I am again getting the previous dataframe

Comment: @user3318064. Show your attempt, and please include data as code, not as a picture.

Comment: Also, you've completely changed the question.

Comment: I'm unclear at the term "remove NaNs" it appears you're just moving `NaN` values to the end of the DataFrame no? Ah I got here after the edit... It's typically bad form to alter the question in a way that invalidates the existing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask is unlikely to work in the general case since the number of dropped NaNs has to match in all columns. If that condition is satisfied, you can do something like this:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'t': ['a', np.nan], 'c': [np.nan, 'b']})
pd.DataFrame({col: x[col].dropna().reset_index(drop=True) for col in x})
```

You are basically splitting the dataframe into series, dropping the NaNs independently, and recombining with the original column names.